# Execute three operations in Mongodb or cancel if just one fails

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to store one record in three different collections at the same time, but I need that if just one of this operations fails (for any kind of reasons) the entire procedure will be canceled. In a few words, I need to be sure that this record is stored correctly in each all the three collections: I need to avoid the situation where the record is stored in just two (or one) collections.

This is my actual code:

```
var insertOne = function(data) {
    req.app.locals.db.collection('document_1').findOneAndUpdate({'id': data.id}, {$set: {'element': 'data.element}}, {returnOriginal: false}, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error 1');
            return;
        }
        if(result) insertTwo(data);
    });
}


var insertTwo = function(data) {
    req.app.locals.db.collection('document_2').findOneAndUpdate({'id': data.id}, {$set: {'element': 'data.element}}, {returnOriginal: false}, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error 2');
            return;
        }
        if(result) insertThree(data);
    });
}

var insertThree = function(data) {
    req.app.locals.db.collection('document_2').findOneAndUpdate({'id': data.id}, {$set: {'element': 'data.element}}, {returnOriginal: false}, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error 3');
            return;
        }
        if(result) console.log('success!');
    });
}

insertOne(mydata);
```

Thanks.

Comment: [`.bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) does explicitly that with the default "ordered" operations. You cannot "find and cancel" though. It's an update all or none operation and if you want to "retrieve" documents, that is a separate operation.

Comment: Actually no. You are asking across collections. There is no way to do that and you need to handle yourself. if it was in "one" collection then it's simply `.bulkWrite()`. Perhaps you should have one collection for this data instead. Why is it across "two" collections?